# Tkinter: how to set the widget property name to be tested in Windows Application Driver

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to use the [Window Application Driver](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/) to test the Tkinter UI widgets, together with [Accessibility Insights for Windows](https://accessibilityinsights.io/) inspector. To test the app, I need to set the property name, which doesn't exist in my inspector. What I've tried is to give [instance names](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/naming-widgets.html) to the widgets, but no luck. Is there any way I can assign the property names for UI testing? Thanks.